# Flutter:Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'

Tags: flutter, dart

when trying to build my apk using vsc i am getting this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
  > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_release:1.0.0-241c87ad800beeab545ab867354d4683d5bfb6ce.
```

Comment: Hi, George. See if one of these two help https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39729#issuecomment-587651515

Comment: where do you put these commands?

Comment: On the terminal in your project directory. On VSCode, go to View > Terminal. Type each command, enter, then wait for it to finish and see if any errors happen.

Comment: i got this error:Target file "precache" not found.